# How can I get the current user in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the current user logged into my Microsoft SQL Server database.

After some research, I have found functions such as `CURRENT_USER` or `USER`, which are supposed to show me the user I am using at that moment.

```sql
SELECT USER, CURRENT_USER
```

The problem is that these functions keep giving me `dbo` as the result, which is, as far as I know, the schema I am using.

Am I not using the correct functions?

Maybe there is any problem with my users?

Comment: Are you looking for `exec sp_who2` ?

Comment: *"The problem is that these functions keep giving me dbo as the result, which is, as far as I know, the schema I am using."* check your users? There might be a `dbo` user?

Comment: `SUSER_NAME()` perhaps?

Comment: I checked before asking and no, there's not a `dbo` user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `SUSER_NAME()` instead of `SYSTEM_USER`. From the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) of `SUSER_NAME()`,

> Returns the login identification name of the user.

Answer (score 8):

You need [SUSER_NAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which gives you the login identification of the current user.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER
```

To understand regarding why you get dbo as answer, suggest reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/server-and-database-roles-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You may use SYSTEM_USER in order to get current username.

You might refer link below to get more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/system-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017